# Empty file in attachment from an uploaded file with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to sent an email with attachment, and get the attachment from an uploaded file from a form. The email is correctly sent, but when I open the attachment it's always an empty file. Is there a mistake in the send attachment code from the controller? Seems like the data inside the file is not saved, leaving the file empty when sending it through.

MODEL:

```
public class Mail{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ButtonClick", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, Mail mail){
    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(mail.File.InputStream,mail.File.FileName));

}
```

Comment: There is no events in MVC (your `ButtonClick` method makes no sense)

Comment: This is just a part of my code. Please refer to the essential issue. Thanks.

Comment: Essential issue?? You have not even shown your controller method that your form posts back to!. How would you expect anyone to guess what mistakes your making!

Comment: Related to the mail sending, I have only set the other fields like To, Subject, and my credentials. The mail is correctly sent. The not functioning part is the attachment. This is the only line I wrote related to the attachment. It sends an empty file, but with the correct name and extension. To me it seems I'm missing to save the contents of the file somehow, somewhere, before sending it in the attachment. This is my "essential issue" :) Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mistake in your code. Everything is fine. Actually the thing is that whenever we want share any file, image or anything in email make sure it is available to any blob or cloud storage and give its link your email.
The files which we share with our emails, actually those just exist on our local machine server or where you have put your project, it does not mean that if you put it in email and share it.

Comment: I don't fully understand you. I used a different code to select a file as attachment from a predefined path from my PC and it sent the attachment correctly and I was able to open it in the mail. But with this code I want to select the file from any folder, not a predefined one, but instead the file I receive in the mail attachment has the right name but it's an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing just the file name to the Attachment constructor.
Through HttpPostedFileBase File you should be able to get the file name and just pass that value and see if it works

Comment: That way it doesn't even send any attachment, so the input stream has to be passed as a first parameter, then the file name is the second paramater. What I don't understand is why the file is empty. Should I copy somehow the value of the file somewhere?